# EF Core 1.1 is this lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I thought lazy loading in EF Core 1.1 is not yet supported but why my code below works ? I am not using Include function for related objects like ProductType, ProductSize but this doesn't cause any error..

Any idea ?

```
List<ProductViewModel> data = await (from s in _context.Product
                                             where ((categorySearchValue == -1 || s.ProductCategoryId == categorySearchValue)
                                             && (typeSearchValue == -1 || s.ProductTypeId == typeSearchValue)
                                             && (sizeSearchValue == -1 || s.ProductSizeId == sizeSearchValue))
                                             select new ProductViewModel
                                             {
                                                 ProductID = s.ProductId,
                                                 ProductName = s.ProductName,
                                                 ProductCategory = s.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryName,
                                                 ProductType = s.ProductType.ProductTypeName,
                                                 ProductSize = s.ProductSize.ProductSizeName,
                                                 CurrentQuantity = s.CurrentQuantity,
                                                 QuantityPerBox = s.QuantityPerBox,
                                                 AvgUnitCost = s.AvgUnitCost,
                                                 MainVendor = s.MainSeller.CustomerName,
                                                 IncludePBox = (Convert.ToBoolean(s.IsPboxIncluded) ? "Y" : "N"),
                                                 Disabled = (s.Inactive ? "Y" : "N"),
                                                 IsTaxProduct = (Convert.ToBoolean(s.IsTaxProduct) ? "Y" : "N"),
                                                 UnitType = s.ProductUnitType.ProductUnitTypeName
                                             }).ToListAsync();
```

Product Model class is as below.

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        TransactionLine = new HashSet<TransactionLine>();
        TransactionLog = new HashSet<TransactionLog>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CurrentQuantity { get; set; }
    public int AvgUnitCost { get; set; }
    public int QuantityPerBox { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? ProductSizeId { get; set; }
    public int? ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ProductUnitTypeId { get; set; }
    public int MainSellerId { get; set; }
    public bool IsTaxProduct { get; set; }
    public bool IsPboxIncluded { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TransactionLine> TransactionLine { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransactionLog> TransactionLog { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer MainSeller { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual Product ProductNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Product InverseProductNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductSize ProductSize { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductUnitType ProductUnitType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features, EF core doesn't support lazy loading, so the answer is no.

Comment: yeah i know it's not supported but apparently the code above which does lazy loading works.  Without using include function i can access the related object see above code. Or I understood something wrong here ?

Comment: Since we don't see your entities, or how you created the model, or how you create the context, etc, it really is impossible to tell.

Comment: I updated with the product class

Answer (score 0):

This is not lazy loading. Lazy loading means that you can access referenced properties after the query is executed. For instance, assuming you have a product with `id = 1` this code:

```
var product = _context.Product.Find(1)
var productSizeName = product.ProductSize.ProductSizeName
```

will give you an exception, since `product.ProductSize` is `null`. To correct this, you would have to do the following:

```
_context.Entry(product).Reference(x => x.ProductSize).Load()
```

and then:

```
var productSizeName = product.ProductSize.ProductSizeName
```

If you used the `product.ProductSize` while creating the query like in you example, it won't give you an error since it is going to use `inner join` to fetch the data.